Parameterized SET query not working in Node.js
So if I run this:
databaseClient.query('SELECT something FROM something WHERE something = $1', [something]);
it works.
But it doesn't work in SET queries, such as:
databaseClient.query('SET myvars.something = $1', [something]);
It works if I do
databaseClient.query(``SET myvars.something = '${myvars.something}'``);
Can someone help me on this?
databaseClient.query('SET myvars.something = $1', [something]);

Should work

Should work. Based on what? Documentation?

Based on how node.js parameterized queries work.
